# Typescript function return class cannot define private member

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, class, mixins

I wonder why I cannot define private members for my returned class that is generated with the below function. Does anyone know why it could not be private and protected?  I saw this code somewhere but in his VS code I did not see any error but it does in my VS code.

```
function myLoggerClass() {
  return  class Logger {
    private completeLog: string = "";
    log(str: string) {
      console.log(str);
      this.completeLog += `${str}\n`;
    }
    dumpLog() {
      return this.completeLog;
    }
  }
}
```

The error says :

```
Errors in code
Property 'completeLog' of exported class expression may not be private or protected.
```

Comment: ① Do you have [the `--declaration` compiler option](//www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#declaration) enabled? If so, then you're generating `.d.ts` files for consumption by external users, and that's why you can't have functions with private members like this (there's no way to represent it properly as a declaration, at least not without some kind of inline class expression declaration as requested in [ms/TS#31581](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41581)). ...

Comment: ... ② If you don't care about making `.d.ts` files then you can disable the config option and the error will go away.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of answering you directly, try understanding this:

```
class MyClass {
  private x: number = 42;
}

function createClass(): typeof MyClass {
  return class MySubClass extends MyClass {
    constructor() {
      super();
      console.log(this.x); // Error: Property 'x' is private and only accessible within class 'MyClass'
    }
  };
}
```

In the above code, the `MyClass` has a private property `x`. The `createClass` function returns a new class `MySubClass` that extends `MyClass` and tries to access the private property `x`. This results in a TypeScript error `TS2341: Property 'x' is private and only accessible within class 'MyClass'.`.

One solution is to define an interface that exposes the public properties and methods of `MyClass`, and have `createClass` return an object that implements that interface instead of returning `MySubClass` directly. Here's the updated code:

```
class MyClass {
  private x: number = 42;
  
  getValue(): number {
    return this.x;
  }
}

interface MyClassInterface {
  getValue(): number;
}

function createClass(): MyClassInterface {
  return {
    getValue: () => {
      const obj = new MyClass();
      return obj.getValue();
    }
  };
}

const myObject = createClass();
console.log(myObject.getValue()); // Output: 42
```

In this updated code, we define an interface `MyClassInterface` that only exposes the public `getValue()` method of `MyClass`. The `createClass` function now returns an object that implements this interface, and uses an instance of `MyClass` to get the value of `x` and return it. This way, the private property `x` is not exposed outside of `MyClass`, and the returned object only has access to the public `getValue()` method.

Answer (score -2):

you could use the get keyword to define your dumpLog() method as an accessor.

```
get dumpLog() {
  return this.completeLog;
}
```